# dynamic binding of functions not working in kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I wanted to make a dynamic class of a group of widget so whenever I add them to my main app, I had to only bring in the changes from somewhere(e.g. a python file, class etc, here I've done them in explicit lists), but binding the widget with properties like "on_text" which respond to events didn't really work, other properties like 'text', 'hint_text' worked perfectly but on_text doesn't really budge. I can't figure out the cause for this because I've checked the correct object being passed along the functions, below is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty



class Dynamic_TextInput(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,changes=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.widgets = {'Mylabel':self.ids.mylabel,
                        'Myinput': self.ids.mytext}
        self.Change(changes)


    def Change(self, changes=None, **kwargs):
        if changes: 
            for change in changes:
                curwidget = self.widgets[change[0]]
                cur_properties = change[1]
                for attr in cur_properties.keys():
                    if attr=='bind':
                        print("The cur properties are: ")
                        print(cur_properties[attr])
                        curwidget.bind(**(cur_properties[attr]))
                    else: 
                        setattr(curwidget, attr, cur_properties[attr])  



class mainwidget(BoxLayout):
    myobj1 = ObjectProperty()
    myobj2 = ObjectProperty() 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation='vertical'


        change1=[('Mylabel', {'text':'firstchange',
            'bind':{'on_text':lambda *_: print('something')}
            }),
                    ('Myinput', {'hint_text': 'Changed hint text'})
                ]

        self.add_widget(Dynamic_TextInput(changes=change1))
        self.add_widget(Dynamic_TextInput())


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return mainwidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

And, in the kivy file:

```
#:kivy 1.10.0


<Dynamic_TextInput>:
    myobj1: mylabel
    myobj2: mytext
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        id: mylabel
        text: 'testlable'
    TextInput:
        id: mytext
        hint_text: 'some test'
```

What is the cause? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to make a binding of a property:

***.py**

```
object.bind(property=callback)
```

***.kv**

```
object:
    on_property: callback
```

So in the case of making the connection in python you should not use `on_text`, but `text`.

To verify the change, the Label can not be edited from the GUI, so I will use the `TextInput` to write on the `Label`:

***.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class Dynamic_TextInput(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,changes=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.widgets = {'Mylabel':self.ids.mylabel,
                        'Myinput': self.ids.mytext}
        self.Change(changes)


    def Change(self, changes=None, **kwargs):
        if changes: 
            for change in changes:
                curwidget = self.widgets[change[0]]
                cur_properties = change[1]
                for attr in cur_properties.keys():
                    if attr=='bind':
                        print("The cur properties are: ")
                        curwidget.bind(**(cur_properties[attr]))
                        print(cur_properties[attr])
                    else: 
                        setattr(curwidget, attr, cur_properties[attr])  


class mainwidget(BoxLayout):
    myobj1 = ObjectProperty()
    myobj2 = ObjectProperty() 
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation='vertical'


        change1=[('Mylabel', {'text':'firstchange',
            'bind':{'text':lambda *_: print('something')}
            }),
                    ('Myinput', {'hint_text': 'Changed hint text'})
                ]

        self.add_widget(Dynamic_TextInput(changes=change1))
        self.add_widget(Dynamic_TextInput())


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return mainwidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

***.kv**

```
#:kivy 1.10.0


<Dynamic_TextInput>:
    myobj1: mylabel
    myobj2: mytext
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Label:
        id: mylabel
        text: mytext.text # <----
    TextInput:
        id: mytext
        hint_text: 'some test'
```